# Using CSS Flex and space-evenly isn't working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've started getting to grips with flex and as soon as I think I have a solid understanding and tried to implement it I find it's not working.

The main issue is the `justify-content: space-evenly` inside my `ul` isn't taking any effect and I can't see why. From everything I've looked at this is correct and should work, I've even seen people using this in tutorials within the same structure.

I placed a border around the element to make sure there is space for it to take up.
I've tried different flex properties, they wont work either. Am I doing something do disable flex?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

[image: Example]

**CSS**

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    max-width: 50%;
}

ul,li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Media Queries</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <ul>

            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Flex Box
</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `display: flex` with your `ul` selector, but afterwards you have another `ul` selector -> `ul,li` where you set `display: inline`
So your are overriding your previous display property

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    ...
}

ul,li {
    display: inline;
    ...
}
```

So you have to change the second selector. Remove `ul` from it.

Also, the `ul` element has a padding by default, remove it with `padding: 0;` in your `ul` selector in order to have it really spaced evenly.
See below example, your `space-evenly` is workign here

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Media Queries</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <ul>

            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Flex Box
</h1>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the "display: inline" from the ul and li selectors.

```
ul,li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: (and add `li {display: inline;}`)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic, it works :

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Media Queries</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>

  <style>
    h1 {
      font-size: 6em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    nav {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    ul {
      border: 1px solid red;
      max-width: 50%;
    }

    ul,
    li {
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#Home">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Flex Box</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're over-writing the `display: flex` of your ul by the line of code below that (`display: inline`). here's the solution below with comments. use `list-style: none` to get rid of the bullet points on li

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    max-width: 50%;
}

ul,li {
  /* -- remove the below line. you're over-writing the display of ul
    display: inline;
    */
    
    /* -- add this below line to get rid of the bullet points */
    list-style: none;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Media Queries</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <ul>

            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Flex Box
</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

tag not working with display:flex; as they used somewhere. Thats why you need to force the ul tag to use flex. You should just wright--

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

you should use !important and everything will be working as you wanted.

Comment: You should avoid using `important` when you can, as you can see in the other answers you can fix the problem easilly without it.